# How to state an activity?

Tags: present-perfect, stative-verbs

How can I state an current state of an activity?

For example:-

The process was completed 
**or** 
The process has completed ?

Comment: Either is fine depending on what you want to say. "Has completed" is usually more recent than "was completed".

Comment: @Peter I got it.. but at a glance both are fine right

Comment: You might also say: *The process is complete* or *The process has been completed*.

Comment: As @Peter said. "The process *was* completed last week." vs. "I can see that the process *has* completed."

Answer (score 1):

> How can I state an current state of an activity?

Present tense.

> The process *is* completed.

The other say that the process completion occurred before now, which is generally going to be always true unless the process literally completed the moment you say this.

If you strictly want to report what the completion state is now then use *is*.

Comment: I agree, a simple "**is**" is enough to speak about the current state of a process.